# SFMC shared email message's images not displaying in Chrome after sent from a different business unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, images, sfmc-business-unit, chrome

Emails from business unit A are shared with B, but when the shared email is sent from business unit B, the email's images do not display in Chrome.

Any insight into why images only display in Chrome when the email is sent from the business unit where the image is stored (business unit A)? Tried sharing the images across all business units to resolve the issue but did not have any luck. Also, all of the image links start with http, so maybe that has something to do with it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You rightly pointed out, its due to non secure portfolio URL... refer this for more details [Customers who use private image domains (SAP) without SSL certificates will see images not load in the Marketing Cloud.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000355099&type=1)